# Pandas: different output from info function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading two different CSV files into dataframes but when I apply `info` function on them I get different outputs:

`df1.info()` shows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 12173793 entries, 0 to 12173792
Data columns (total 44 columns):
ID                             int64
CODE_x                         object
SECTOR                         object
```

`df2.info()` shows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 641683 entries, 0 to 641682
Data columns (total 19 columns):
ID                   641683 non-null object
SALE_VALUE           641683 non-null int64
SALE_DATE            641683 non-null object
CODE                 625726 non-null object
```

Why do I see count of `non-null` in 2nd DataFrame?

**Edit**

From the accepted answer below. As I have set these options at start

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('float_format', '{:.0f}'.format)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Pandas [info documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html):

> null_counts : bool, optional
>
> Whether to show the non-null counts. By
> default, this is shown only if the frame is smaller than
> pandas.options.display.max_info_rows and
> pandas.options.display.max_info_columns. A value of True always shows
> the counts, and False never shows the counts.

So if you do not want to see the null counts, set this value to false for the second data frame like this:

```
df2.info(null_counts=False)
```